# Font Awesome with Half Style CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I'm wondering if anyone can help me / If this is even possible.

I'm trying to half style (using halfstyle.js) the youtube font-awesome icon so that the icon is like the youtube logo (bottom half red, top half white)

I'd like to do this on hover, but I can't even seem to get this going for just as default.

**[`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ogxwpdmd/)**

```css
body {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.fa {
    font-size: 10em;
    color: white;
}
.fa-youtube {}

.halfStyle {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:80px; /* or any font size will work */
    color: transparent; /* hide the base character */
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: pre; /* to preserve the spaces from collapsing */
}
.halfStyle:before { /* creates the top part */
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 50%;
    content: attr(data-content); /* dynamic content for the pseudo element */
    overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* so the base char is selectable by mouse */
    color: #f00; /* for demo purposes */
    text-shadow: 2px -2px 0px #af0; /* for demo purposes */
}
.halfStyle:after { /* creates the bottom part */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    content: attr(data-content); /* dynamic content for the pseudo element */
    overflow:hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* so the base char is selectable by mouse */
    color: #000; /* for demo purposes */
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #0af; /* for demo purposes */
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-youtube textToHalfStyle"></i>
```

Comment: Looking for something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/ogxwpdmd/3) ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay No I'm just looking for the 'tube box' to go red and the rest stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that for FontAwesome `i.fa` icons because, already HalfStyle is based on the `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements. Also, FontAwesome uses `:after` for this. You need to create another element and give `:hover` option for achieving this.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".textToHalfStyle").each(function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="cloned"></div>');
    $(".cloned").append($(this).clone());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  font-size: 160px;
}
.fa {
  color: #fff;
}
.cloned {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 8px;
  top: 76px;
  height: 0.65em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cloned .fa {
  position: relative;
  top: -68px;
  color: #f00;
}
.fa:hover ~ .cloned,
.cloned:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-youtube textToHalfStyle"></i>
```

Comment: I would like for the icon to be white, and then on hover it would display like you have it (no red on top)

Comment: @Tom Need some time to figure it out. `:P`

Comment: Thank you ever so much!!